# Parameters Correlation in STAN

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, fitting, stan

I am fitting a simple normal distribution in stan through R.
The distribution depends on two parameters, $\mu$ and $\sigma$.
Here the sample code:

```
library(rstan)

n <- 100
mu <- 4
sigma <- 2

Y <- rnorm(100, mu, sigma)

stan_code <- "
  data {
    int N;
    real y[N];
  }

  parameters {
    real mu;
    real sigma;
  }

  model {
    mu ~ normal(0, 10);
    sigma ~  cauchy(0, 10);
    y ~ normal(mu, sigma);
  }
"

stan_input <- list(N = n, y = Y)
stan_model <- stan_model(model_code = stan_code)

fit <- sampling(stan_model, data = stan_input)

results <- extract(fit)

mean(results$mu)
# [1] 3.888839
mean(results$sigma)
# [1] 1.792918
```

This all makes sense and no major issues here. The problem comes next.
Let's assume I would like to do some sampling on the final distribution, given the posterior distributions of the parameters.
The question I have is: Are the posteriors correlated or independence is assumed here?
If I want them to be correlated in any way, shall I explicitly write the stan code to take the correlation into account?

Thank you,
Marco